# How to find the raw header of a website using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, http-headers, urllib

I'm learning something about the website by myself. and I'm trying to fetch the raw header followed by the 3-digit HTTP return code from a website. 
Here is what I did so far:

```
import urllib.request
with urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=clippers+vs+lakers') as response:
    html_text = response.read()
print(html_text)
```

It prints everything from the source. Then I use "Command + F" to search for some key word like "raw header", but I cannot find something useful.
Can somebody help me get the raw header from the page source please? Is there some library to do that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest and more elegant way is to use requests library

```
import requests as req

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=clippers+vs+lakers'

response = req.get(url)

headers = response.headers

html = response.text
```

Comment: what is the 3-digit HTTP return code? the prompt says the headers is followed by a 3-digit return code

Comment: @junjunbaobao use response.status_code to get the HTTP return code

Answer (score 0):

Try `response.info()` method to get the headers.